# jQuery inArray() locating HTML element

Tags: jquery, arrays

Say,I have 5 paragraphs in the page.

if I execute:

```
p_array=$('p');
second_p=$('p:eq(1)');
$.inArray(second_p,p_array);
```

I get -1.
Any explanation?

Comment: `second_p` is a jQuery object, and `p_array` is an array-like object which contains DOM nodes... Therefore, `p_array` obviously does not contain `second_p`.

Comment: Why not `second_p = p_array.eq(1);`? You're doing two look-ups unnecessarily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither `p_array` nor `second_p` are arrays.

They are jQuery objects.

More specifically, `p_array` is a jQuery object containing a set of 5 DOM nodes. `second_p` is a jQuery object containing a set of 1 DOM node.

`$.inArray` can function on these jQuery sets of nodes, but you can't compare a set against a set.

If you extract that one DOM node using the *array subscript operator* (`jQueryObj[i]`), then you're no longer comparing a set against a set:

```
var p_array=$('p');
var second_p=$('p:eq(1)');
alert($.inArray(second_p[0], p_array)); // result: 1
```

See a live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tg9t7/).

Comment: @xiaohan2012: Yea, we like it :)

Answer (score 1):

Both `p_array` and `second_p` are array-like jQuery objects. You want to extract the actual DOM node for the `<p>` and test it like:

```
$.inArray(second_p[0], p_array);
```

That call returns `1` for me, as expected.